# Browse an api from mobile running by pc's localhost

Tags: api, go

If my api is running on my pc, when I browse **localhost:3000/purchases** I get this json response.

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  }
]
```

Now I want to get the same response by visiting **the exact same url** from mobile

[ both are under same wifi network ]

What should I do?

[ my server is golang with postgres, my client is angular, but I also want to see json response from my mobile ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get your local ip of your PC :

- win + R
- write "cmd"
- write "ipconfig /all"
- find you local ipV4 "192.168.x.x"

Now you just have to visiting : "192.168.x.x/purchases"

If you really want to use "localhost:3000/purchases" to access it by your mobile, you need to install an adroid Web server app

Comment: where can I find this web server app ?

Comment: Check https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws&hl=fr